# Yii: Why CPortlet doesn't have the renderDynamic method?

Tags: caching, yii

I'm using caching in both some controllers and some Portlet extending `CPortlet`. Controllers have methods `beginCache`, `endCache` and `renderDynamic`, the last one letting us register some dynamic content in the cached section.

CPortlet has `beginCache` and `endCache` but not `renderDynamic`.

So why this Class hasn't renderDynamic, and how could I replace it?

Answer (score 0):

The creator of yii answered it in a post on the official forum:

```
$this->controller->renderDynamic()
```

[Source](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11692-dynamic-rendering-in-widget-view/)

Since a Portlet is just a specific Widget I assume it'll work the same!